# SPARQL transitive query for multiple hierarchical relationships

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have a tree that I would like to transitively traverse.

A problem I am facing is that I have a parent concept:

```
parentConcept -> hierRelationship1 -> child -> hierRelationship2 -> 
     -> grandChild -> hierelationship3 -> greatGrandChild -> hierelationship2 -> greatGreatGrandChild
```

So basically I have several hierarchical relationships that intermingle the hierarchy. I do know that all direct children of the parentConcept have a relationship of `skos:broader` - it is the grandchild+ where things get hairy.

What I have tried so far is:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT ?child
WHERE {

    ?rel rdfs:subPropertyOf skos:broader  .  # get subPropertyOf rels
    ?child skos:broader <parentConcept> .
    ?grandchild ?rel ?child
    }
```

Ideally, I would like to 'unpack' my ?rel variable so that I can add the transitive operator (+) to each relationships within this variable but I am not sure if this is possible within sparql.

Does anyone see a better way to do this or am I on the right track?

> I have also tried including OPTIONAL{} queries ,e.g. `OPTIONAL {grandchild2 ?rel grandchild}` but this is very slow and feels unwieldy

Comment: I doubt this is possible with a single SPARQL query. A common workaround is to get all properties `p1, ..., pn` via a SPARQL query and then, in a second query use the property path `(p1|...|pn)+` - not sure if this is what you need though

Comment: Is there a way to unpack a variable? e.g. `?rel` holds 3 variables, any way to get `?var1. ?var2 ?var3`. I wasn't aware of the `(p1|p2|....|pn)+` trick... that could work if I explicitly include the relationships

Comment: not sure if I understand correctly, but if I do then no, something like pivot operation in SQL does not exists, so you won't get 3 columns out of a single columns.